# How does this query stop?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking at [this query](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/hugeupdate/) and I am kinda confused by a few things.

```
-- T-SQL large update table
USE tempdb;
SELECT * INTO SOD
FROM AdventureWorks2008.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GO
--(121317 row(s) affected)

-- SQL update in batches of 10,000
WHILE (2 > 1)
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE TOP ( 10000 ) SOD
    SET    UnitPriceDiscount = 0.08,
           ModifiedDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),getdate(),112))
    WHERE  ModifiedDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),getdate(),112))

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
         BREAK
      END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    -- 1 second delay
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  END -- WHILE
GO

/* Messages

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(10000 row(s) affected)

(1317 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
*/
-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE SOD
GO

------------
```

1. Is it making a temp table? `SELECT * INTO SOD` if so is this really needed? Can I just use the while part and below?
2. How does   `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` ever become zero? Does it do some self incrementing or something?

**Edit**

This is what I have now but I still think there is an endless loop or something

```
BEGIN TRAN

declare
  @rows_updated int ,
  @rowCount int,
  @batch_size   int
  set @rows_updated = -1
  set @batch_size   = 10000
  set @rowCount = 0;

Declare @xx VARCHAR(20) DECLARE @length INT
SET @length = 17 SET @xx = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

while ( @rows_updated != 0 )
  begin
    update top(@batch_size)  myTbl
    SET myNumber = SUBSTRING(@xx, 0, @length - len(RIGHT(myNumber, 4))) + RIGHT(myNumber, 4) 
    WHERE myDate <'2011-Jan-02' 
    set @rows_updated = @@rowcount
   set @rowCount += 10000
    print @rowCount
  end

ROLLBACK
```

I did a count

```
select count(*) from myTbl
where  myDate < '2011-Jan-02'
```

this brings back a count of `1,448,982`

the last print out I got was `31,110,000`

**Edit 2**

I added this and now it stops but it still is not 100% where it should be at

```
while (Select Count(*) From myTbl Where myDate  <'2011-Jan-02' ) >=  @rowCount
```

Edit 3

I think edit 2 is just doing the same 10,000 rows over and over again.

Comment: your first edit is almost correct. You forgot one thing, though: you're not updating the column `mydate`. The updated rows need to be modified such that they will no longer satisify the condition(s) in the `where` clause. If you don't do that, you'll just endlessly update rows. Also, where you're adding to your accumulator to print the running total, `set @rowCount += 10000`, you shouldn't be adding 10000 to the accumulator, you should be adding `@rows_updated`. The `top` clause caps at no more than X. The very last batch will be 0 rows; the 2nd less almost certainly less than 10000.

Comment: @NicholasCarey - I am unsure what to use though to statisfy the condition to make the rows stop. I can't update myDate and I not sure how to write something to see if myNumber has been updated.

Comment: Your where clause could check to see if the column 'MyNumber' has already been masked: if it starts with an `X` (or 17 `X`s), it's already been masked, so you're not interested in it, correct?

Comment: @NicholasCarey -I guess so. Would I do a like on it?

Comment: That would probably be the easiest way, so long as you're sure you won't find rows that can't be updated (null?) with a mask. A positive test for rows that **should** be masked, (e.g., starting with 17 decimal digits), something along the lines of  `where my_column like '[0-9]...[0-9]'`) might be safer as it would guarantee that you'd eventually exhaust the set of candidate rows.

Comment: @NicholasCarey - Ya there seems to be null fields. Another problem I am running into it seems to be taking a long time to do updates. I tried to reduce the batch size to like 100 then put a print statement as the first line in the while loop and last line(right before "end") and that it take a very very long time to reach my last print statement. So it seems like it may take days or weeks to do them all. So trying to also get it to be alot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided script does the following:

- Creates/Loads the permanent table SOD
- while (true)

  - begins a transaction
  - updates at most 10,000 rows of the SOD table, where the modified date is less than the current date, setting the unit price discount to 0.08 and setting the modified date to the current date.
  - commits the transaction
  - if no rows were modified, exits the loop
  - repeat

First, the `begin transaction` and `commit transaction` are unnecessary with a normal installation of SQL Server, unless you've explicitly changed the `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` setting by executing `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`, in which case the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement is unecessary. The reason is the by default, SQL Servers runs in auto-commit mode, so every statement fires, *sotto voce*, a `commit` on success or a `rollback` on failure.

Also, the logic is a little clunky. I'd write the loop like this:

```
declare
  @rows_updated int ,
  @batch_size   int

set @rows_updated = -1
set @batch_size   = 10000

while ( @rows_updated != 0 )
  begin

    update top @batch_size SOD
    set UnitPriceDiscount = 0.08 ,
        ModifiedDate      = convert(datetime,convert(char(10),getdate(),112))
    where ModifiedDate    < convert(datetime,convert(char(10),getdate(),112))

    set @rows_updated = @@rowcount

  end
```

which might make what's going on a little more transparent.

Comment: Ya this does make it look a bit cleaner. I am wondering anyway that I can print out how many rows have been updated like when the first batch would be done it would print out 10,000 next one time would print 20,000(10,000 + 10,00). So I can see how many it's done and can start to figure out how long the query will take instead of just looking at it and wondering what it is doing.

Comment: @chobo2: I've been known to create a logging table, and log the progress in that. Makes it a little easier to peer into the block box without using something like SQL Trace.

Comment: No easier way like to print out a line or something to the output?

Answer (score 2):

1. `SOD` is a new table created by the `SELECT ... INTO` statement, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx)
2. `@@ROWCOUNT` gets to 0 when the prior `UPDATE` statement no longer updates any records, or in other words, when all the records in the `SOD` table have already been updated.

**EDIT** fixed first answer

Comment: So do I have to make a another table with the same structure? Or can I just use the while loop?

Comment: @chobo2 I made a mistake. `SELECT ... INTO X` creates a new table and populates it with the result set of the `SELECT` statement

Comment: @chobo2 You can just use the `WHILE` loop, but you can't reference `SOD` because it wouldn't have been created.  You'd have to reference the `SalesOrderDetail` table in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Shark is right: the reason `SOD` is created in the query is just as a temp table, to avoid modifying the real `SalesOrderDetail` table. The last part of the script drops the `SOD` table anyway, since this is just meant as a test / demonstration of the `WAITFOR DELAY` statement

Comment: Ya so basically ignore this table they made for no reason(as it gets dropped) and update the table I want to update. I can always wrap it in a transaction begin / rollback to test to see if it works good.

Answer (score 0):

It is not making a temp table, the `SELECT ... INTO SOD FROM ...` is creating an exact copy (data and schema) of the `SalesOrderDetail` table.  The table `SOD` cannot exist prior to this statement, otherwise SQL Server will throw an error.  And unlike a temp table, `SOD` will persist until a `DROP TABLE` is run on it.  A temp table only exists for the duration of the creating process ID (or, since you are creating the table in `tempdb`, it will go away the next time SQL Server restarts).

`@@rowcount` will be zero if there are no rows effected by the last DML statement.  In other words, when there are no rows updated, `@@rowcount` will be zero and break out of the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's making a copy of `AdventureWorks2008.Sales.SalesOrderDetail` in the `tempdb`. It then `UPDATE` the `SOD` table `10000` records at a time. This is done when tables are large as smaller transactions complete quicker, resulting in less contention for the table.

`@@ROWCOUNT` is updated internally after any DML statement, unless `SET ROWCOUNT OFF` is specified. So eventually, `SOD` won't have any qualifying records and none will be updated, which ends the loop.

The whole thing seems kind of pointless as `SOD` is thrown out in the end. So unless there's more to this code I can't understand why a copy is being made, updated, then dropped.

Comment: This is a table the user made or is it generating it on the fly?

Comment: @chobo2 it is generating `SOD` on the fly, but `SalesOrderDetail` must exist prior to this statement.

Comment: It's generated on-the-fly. `SELECT ... INTO` syntax does an implicit `CREATE TABLE` using the shape of the data returned by the `SELECT` statement for its definition.

Comment: @Yuck: The notion that batching big updates like this is better is not neccesarily true. You need to test that empirically. I can personally attest to having to remove code like this and revert to a single massive update, because the batched approach took too long (something like 50% longer than a single `update`, IIRC) and caused far more blocking/contention, per the production DBAs traces than the single massive update. In the bizarre world inhabited by SQL and relational databases, that which should be true is not necessarily so.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Obviously. I was explaining why this code is written as it is. I was not advocating doing this in all cases.